# overriding cart.phtml issue not working for notitems.phtml

Tags: magento

Hello  i working on overriding the cart.phtml and it is working fine. but the problem is that when no item left in the cart still the it showing the cart table header and footer section without any item. i want when no item is present in the cart then it will show the noitem.phtml content as it is working for default magetno functionality.

i have check many things but not working . i have update my layout.xml but not effect any thing.

My layout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>itemdeletion/cart.phtml</template></action>      
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>itemdeletion/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>itemdeletion/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
         <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>itemdeletion/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
 </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

it is working for cart items but i make few more R & D and try to figure out how i can make it but i have get to add below blocks in xml

```
<action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>itemdeletion/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
<action method="chooseTemplate"/>
```

but still it not working. Please help me out in this.
    Thanks in advance